# Set a cron every certain hours and restart after some time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I set a cron to run everyday from 12 am to 11am on every 10 mins and after 11am it will stop for 20 mins and start again at 11:20 am i.e. it has to skip 11:10 am run and jump directly to 11:20 am in everyday basis, could any one help me how to do that in Spring-boot?

Answer (score 0):

what I understand by restarting is you need to run every 20 minutes , below expression may help you

0 0/20 0-22 * * MON-FRI

I added the day incase you need it to run on weekdays else you can have *

you can build cron expression https://crontab.cronhub.io/ here useful
also http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Connect/en/Writing_a_CRON_Expression is good to read once

Comment: Thanks for hep!! but it has to run every 10 mins and at 11:00 am it will stop, again start at 11:20 am directly means it will skip 11:10 am run. Is it possible?

Comment: in that case you need multiple expression for example first one is 
 "0 0/10 0-22 * * MON-FRI"  which will run every 10 minutes till 10.59 then the second one will run from 11.20 every 10 minutes for that hour only "0 10-59,0/10 23 * * MON-FRI" , however I am not sure how the 2nd expression will behave please give it a try, if its working please post it